# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

I am having a issue while saving the image file in MognoDB. It is saying the error

> (node:14849) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

While I searched for the error solution, it was said that I am sending the result after it is sent. I am checking my code it is not like that. Can anyone help me with this to find the error please?

**imageUpload.js**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const uploadImage = require("../../models/fileUpload");

const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "uploads",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: Storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
}).single("testImage");

const imageUpload = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err)
        res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          message: "Saving Failed",
        });

      const newImage = new uploadImage({
        name: req.body.name,
        image: {
          data: req.body.image,
          contentType: "image/png",
        },
      });

      newImage
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            msg: "Saved Successfully",
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            msg: error.data,
          });
        });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = { imageUpload };
```

Comment: i am seeing you are not using return before sending response to client add return before every response you sent it will fix the error and also its a good habbit

Comment: you are sending response to user 3 times 
see on line 23
then on 38
then on 44

Comment: @MubasherAli, Yes. But all response are getting sent on certain conditions right?

Comment: i think you first response is sending if you got error then if you got error then catch block will also run? then that response will also sent that's why its giving that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't properly defined the **if** condition with else.

> Here is the code below rewritten.

**imageUpload.js**

```
const multer = require("multer");
const uploadImage = require("../../models/fileUpload");

// const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
//   destination: "uploads",
//   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
//     const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
//     cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix);
//   },
// });

const upload = multer({
  // storage: Storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
}).single("testImage");

const imageUpload = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          message: "Saving Failed",
        });
      } else {
        const newImage = new uploadImage({
          name: req.body.name,
          image: {
            data: req.body.image,
            contentType: "image/png",
          },
        });

        newImage
          .save()
          .then(() => {
            res.status(201).json({
              success: true,
              msg: "Saved Successfully",
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
              success: false,
              msg: error.data,
            });
          });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = { imageUpload };
```

Answer (score 1):

return before sending response to client add return before every response you sent it will fix the error and also its a good habbit